# Сортировка JS объекта

Tags: javascript, сравнение

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую задачу:

1. Есть объект — массив элементов с одинаковыми параметрами (пример ниже).
2. Функция принимает на вход три значения параметров.
3. Перебирает элементы объекта и отбирает те, параметры которых совпадают с переданными в функцию.

   - Значения могут быть не заданы, в таком случае сравнивать по ним не нужно.
4. Возвращает массив отобранных элементов.

Пример объекта:

```
var items={};
items[1]={
    param_1:"10",
    param_2:"521А2",
    param_3:"A",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
}    
items[2]={
    param_1:"15",
    param_2:"521А1",
    param_3:"B",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
}
items[50]={
    param_1:"10",
    param_2:"521А3",
    param_3:"C",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
}
```

Функция должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
function get_table(data){
    for (i in items) {
        //Магический IF =)
        if(все параметры сходятся у элемента items[i]){
            consle.log(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

И вызываться так:

```
get_table({
  param_1: 10,
  param_2: '521А2',
  param_3: 'A',
});
get_table({
  param_2: '521А1',
  param_3: 'B',
});
```

Сейчас я перебираю данный объект с помощью цикла `for`
и в процессе сравниваю параметры: `param_1`, `param_2`, `param_3`. Проблема в том, что получается слишком много блоков `if...else`:

```
if(items[i].param_1 == param_1){ console.log(items[i]); }
if(items[i].param_2 == param_2){ console.log(items[i]); }
if(items[i].param_3 == param_1){ console.log(items[i]); }
if(items[i].param_1 == param_1 && items[i].param_2 == param_2){ console.log(items[i]); }
if(items[i].param_2 == param_2 && items[i].param_3 == param_3){ console.log(items[i]); }
if(items[i].param_3 == param_3 && items[i].param_1 == param_1){ console.log(items[i]); }
```

Как сделать лучше?

Comment: по объяснению непонятно что ты получаешь на входе и что ожидается на выходе. Что с чем сравниваешь тоже непонятно

Comment: Эта ваша сортировка у приличных людей называется `фильтрация`

Comment: Напишите пример входа и выхода. Типа: `Input: ... тут_фильрация ... Output: ...`.

Comment: Слегка переформулировал ваш вопрос.

Comment: Про сортировку непонятно по-прежнему. Если она нужна — то опишите подробнее, по каким полям и в каком порядке сортировать? (ну и вообще, про неё стоит задать другой вопрос)

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так?

```js
var items={};
items[1]={
    param_1:"10",
    param_2:"521А2",
    param_3:"A",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
};    
items[2]={
    param_1:"15",
    param_2:"521А1",
    param_3:"B",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
};
items[50]={
    param_1:"10",
    param_2:"521А3",
    param_3:"C",
    anydata:"bla-bal"
};

function filter(items, test) {
  var res = [];
  for (item in items) {
    var match = true;
    for (field in test) {
      if (items[item][field] !== test[field]) {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match)
      res.push(items[item]);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(filter(items, {param_3: "B"}));
console.log(filter(items, {param_1: "10", param_3: "C"}));
```

Comment: Интересно, за что минусы. Кстати, посмотрите на вопрос, я его там переделал. Верно задачу понял? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Самому интересно. Тут у меня сейчас массовое минусование. Жду отката :)

Comment: Ну тогда от меня плюс.